# Ruby―parse #{…} in string

Tags: ruby, replace

I am a bit new to Ruby and I would like to substitute local variables in a String. If I have:

```
user = "foo"
pass = "bar"
puts "if you #{user}, you should #{bar}" 

#prints: if you foo, you should bar
```

But in my case the String is a line of text from a file, so not declared at parse time. Is there any built in function with which I can catch up this mechanism?

Comment: Don't use string interpolation. Use format strings and [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Comment: No, but it can't work with static strings stored in a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string = "if you %{user}, you should %{pass}"
string % {user: "foo", pass: "bar"}
# => "if you foo, you should bar"
```

Comment: @Singleton see [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25).